# Creating a custom piecewise loss function in tf.keras with three variables

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am using the following code to try and train a model using a custom piecewise loss function that incorporates three variables but I am unable to get it to work. I am new to tensorflow so if anyone has any suggestions that would be helpful.

I want to incorporate a third variable "p" into the loss function where "p" varies with each y_true/y_pred pair. "p" represents one column from the original dataframe. For this problem "p" is crucial to determining if the model is correct or not. If the model is correct I assign a loss of zero and if its incorrect I assign a loss of one. I sum the loss values and divide by the batch size to determine the loss value for that batch. Is what I am trying to do even possible? And if not, what is an alternative way I could achieve my intended outcome.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Read in statistics and outcomes dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(r'gs.csv')
df = df.drop(['prediction_ou'], axis=1)

# Change categorical columns to numeric
df['date'] = pd.Categorical(df['date'])
df['date'] = df.date.cat.codes

df['away_team'] = pd.Categorical(df['away_team'])
df['away_team'] = df.away_team.cat.codes

df['away_conf'] = pd.Categorical(df['away_conf'])
df['away_conf'] = df.away_conf.cat.codes

df['home_team'] = pd.Categorical(df['home_team'])
df['home_team'] = df.home_team.cat.codes

df['home_conf'] = pd.Categorical(df['home_conf'])
df['home_conf'] = df.home_conf.cat.codes

# Create target data
target = df.pop('actual_spread')

# Create tensorflow dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))

# Shuffle and batch
train_dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(df)).batch(32)

# Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1)
])
  


#  Custom loss function  
def cbb_loss_higher(p):
    
    def cbb_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        c=0
        
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
            if ((y_true[i]>p[i]) and (y_pred[i]<p[i])) or ((y_true[i]<p[i]) and (y_pred[i]>p[i])):
                c+=1
            elif ((y_true[i]>p[i]) and (y_pred[i]>p[i])) or ((y_true[i]<p[i]) and (y_pred[i]<p[i])):
                c+=0
            else:
                c+=0.5
                
        cbb_loss = c/len(y_true)
        return cbb_loss
   

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=cbb_loss_higher(p = df.prediction_spread),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=10)
```

When the code is run as is I receive the following error:

```
File "cbb_ml.py", line 129, in <module>
    epochs=10)
...
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradients of Logical Operators in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990115/gradients-of-logical-operators-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Your problem is your custom loss function is not differentiable. Try creating labels for your data. Map your three cases to labels (0, 1, 2). Then have your network output 3 units in a dense layer, and use cross_entropy as your loss.

Answer (score 0):

Loss function is a part of computation graph built by keras. You can not use python `len()` function within it. This function don't support backpropagation of gradient. Replace it by `tf.shape()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just re-arranged your cost function a little bit. Since I did not have your csv file, I mocked some inputs and a simple model.

```
p = tf.random.normal(shape=[10])

#  Custom loss function  

def cbb_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        c=0.0
        
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
            if ((y_true[i]>p[i]) and (y_pred[i]<p[i])) or ((y_true[i]<p[i]) and (y_pred[i]>p[i])):
                c+=1.0
            elif ((y_true[i]>p[i]) and (y_pred[i]>p[i])) or ((y_true[i]<p[i]) and (y_pred[i]<p[i])):
                c+=0.0
            else:
                c+=0.5
                
        cbb_loss = c/tf.cast(len(y_true),dtype=tf.float32)
        return cbb_loss

x = tf.random.normal(shape=(10,10))
y = tf.random.normal(shape=(10,1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=cbb_loss,
          metrics=['accuracy'])    


model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=100,verbose=1)
```